# HTC 510 is vibrating uncontrolablly

Tags: notifications

My HTC 510 is vibrating uncontrollably , but there isn't any notification. What to do ? Its becoming very annoying! Please get to me as soon as anyone can, thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Check Settings, Accessibility and ensure that Notification reminder is off.